# When you pass a lambda function as a parameter to as Task, is it run on the Task thread or the caller thread?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

`Handler` is passed a delegate, which it should call in certain cases:

```
            var h = new Handler((msg) =>
                {
                    LogAlert(msg);
                });
```

`Handler` internally uses TPL and asynchronous code, so the lamda is called from a TPL threadpool thread.

Does the fact we're passing a lambda have any impact on threading - I am asking because lambdas can capture variables, so I wondered if they can capture thread-state or if it's just a regular function call? Does anything clever happen here?

Comment: (I have tried to test but when it comes to MT, you don't always get the same answer so something definitive would be useful)

Comment: The code is always run on the thread that calls it.  Dispatchers mitigate this by listening to events and calling a function on a specific thread, but this requires message pumping on the thread. If you want to share variables within async contexts, I think what you are looking for is async locals. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netcore-3.1